# Google PubSub subscriber doesn't pull messages after first message in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

**Summary:**
I have a Node.js application that publishes the messages to Google PubSub, and there is a subscriber that pulls the data from PubSub. While doing so, I noticed that subscriber is pulling notifications for the first time, but it does not pull any messages from subscriber after that.The application does not have a high volume of traffic: it is assumed that the publisher can send one message every one second.

Note: I have to restart PM2 server to get the second message.

I am not able to figure out why the subscriber is not able to pull after the first message. I would appreciate any assistance.

Publisher code:

```
 const postNotificationsService = async (payload) => {
  try {

    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload));
    console.log("Connected to Producer");
    console.log("Successfully posted to web notification Queue");
    let publishRes = await pubsub
      .topic(topicName)
      .publishMessage({ data: dataBuffer });

    console.log(publishRes)
    return { message: "Success" };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
};
```

Subscriber Code:

```
const pullSubscriptionsMessage = () => {
  // const subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscriptionName);

  const subscriberOptions = {
    flowControl: {
      maxMessages: maxInProgress,
    },
  };

  // References an existing subscription.
  // Note that flow control settings are not persistent across subscribers.
  const subscription = pubsub.subscription(
    subscriptionName,
    subscriberOptions
  );

  console.log(
    `Subscriber to subscription ${subscription.name} is ready to receive messages at a controlled volume of ${maxInProgress} messages.`
  );

  // Create an event handler to handle messages
  let messageCount = 0;
  const messageHandler = async message => {
    console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
    // console.log(`Data: ${message.data}`);
    // console.log(`tAttributes: ${message.attributes}`);
    messageCount += 1;
    let messagePayload = JSON.parse(message.data.toString())
    await mailerService.sendEmail(messagePayload);

    await message.ack();
  };

  

  // Listen for new messages/errors until timeout is hit
  subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscription.close();
    console.log(`${messageCount} message(s) received.`);
  }, timeout * 1000);

}

pullSubscriptionsMessage();
```

Output:

```
0|serverHTTP  | Connected to Producer
0|serverHTTP  | Successfully posted to web notification Queue
0|serverHTTP  | Received message 6339231272672371:
0|serverHTTP  | 6339231272672371
0|serverHTTP  | 1 message(s) received.
0|serverHTTP  | Connected to Producer
0|serverHTTP  | Successfully posted to web notification Queue
0|serverHTTP  | 6339223654064343
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out this line: `await mailerService.sendEmail(messagePayload);`? What is the value of `timeout`? Is `sendEmail()` throwing an exception?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, Thanks for your reply! Even after commenting `await mailerService.sendEmail(messagePayload);` line it doesn't work and throws no errors. I don't know what caused the issue. 
`timeout=60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified, the subscriber is only running for `timeout` seconds before shutting down. If you want the subscriber to run indefinitely, you shouldn't have the `setTimeout` that closes the subscriber. You can see in the output that it shut down: `1 message(s) received.`